# How can I reboot system using Upstart?

Tags: linux, process, reboot, daemon, upstart

I'm using Upstart on Ubuntu 12.04  to control and monitor a service defined by me, where the service is a user process running as a daemon.
I need to monitor it so, when it fails/crashes it respawns, if it needs to start another processes the upstart scripts do it on the fly with the available stanzas. Until there so far, I hace managed it to work, but now I need to reboot system if the desired process, if tried to respawn "n" number of times and failed, cannot start again.

How can I accomplish this? Can I do it using Upstart as well or maybe I need to include another kind of script or daemon?

Any help will be appreciated.
PD.- By the way, can I change how many respawns will Upstart waits till reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, because lack of a better answer I'm using just the `shutdown -r` command.
I understand it's a bad practice, that's why I thought Upstart had another way to do this but , in view of my boss asking me to achieve this, I'll just reboot system if respawning the process fails several times.